# ActivePivot with a rules engine

Tags: activepivot

I have just started on a project which his regulatory in nature and the business area of the IB I work with uses ActivePivot to manage their securities (inventory).
One of the tasks we need to do is that the ActivePivot data set and run some sort of simple rules engine over the data that feeds ActivePivot. There is a little bit of netting involved at the transactional level but it's mostly simply rules using basic operators. I haven't used ActivePivot before but the users are telling me it doesn't really allow them to add fields within the cube which I understand from a technical perspective. I also noted that ActiveViam have a product called ActiveUI which on the surface appears to do this?
Has any one any tips/advice on what worked for them? The business also want a better data visualisation tool (graphs and the likes).. I was looking at tableaux but open to suggestions. Many thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 3):

There is no clear question here so I will answer to your different points one by one:

> run some sort of simple rules engine over the data that feeds ActivePivot

Then you can add your rule engine in your project on the data set before feeding ActivePivot as if you were not using ActivePivot afterwards.

> users are telling me it doesn't really allow them to add fields within the cube

you cannot add fields once the cube is started but you can update the description of your cube in your project to integrate the new fields brought by your new logic.

> I also noted that ActiveViam have a product called ActiveUI which on the surface appears to do this?

ActiveUI is a UI for the ActiveViam products (including ActivePivot), so it provides you (among others) tables, charts to navigate your data.

> The business also want a better data visualisation tool (graphs and the likes).. I was looking at tableaux but open to suggestions

ActiveUI can provide you this. ActivePivot follows the standard for OLAP databases (XMLA) so it is also compatible with other XMLA clients like Excel and Tableau. Your BI has probably already chosen which client they would use so you should see with them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and apologies if my question was unclear .. I'm trying to work out the best way of achieving an end result and was wondering if anyone could reccomend a rules engine that play nicely with active pivot